# The intersection of a locally finite family of open sets is a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{ U_i : i \in I \}$ be a [locally finite family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_collection) of open sets, if $I$ is infinite index, and there exist infinite different $U_i$, must $\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i $ be a closed set?

Or, further more,

if $\{ U_i : i \in I \}$ are different open sets, that is to say, for any $i,j  \in I, i \neq j $, $U_i \neq U_j$, then must $\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i $ be a closed set?

Or,
if $\{ U_i : i \in I \}$ are disjoint open sets, that is to say, for any $i,j  \in I, i \neq j $, $U_i \bigcap U_j= \emptyset $, then must $\bigcap_{i \in I} U_i $ be a closed set?

Comment: I think the intersection of any infinite but locally finite family of sets is the empty set.

Comment: @Rolf Hoyerthe:intersection of any infinite but locally finite family of open sets is the empty set?

Comment: Any point has a neighborhood intersecting only finitely many sets in the family.  Therefore, there are infinitely many sets in the family not containing it, so our given point is not in the intersection.

Comment: @Rolf Hoyerthe:I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @RolfHoyer I understand why our given point wouldn't be in the intersection, but why wouldn't there be any points in the intersection? Is it because the given point is arbitrary and we could do this game for all points in the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Rolf Hoyer points out, this is always empty.
2. No, let $U_i$ be composed of a set $U$ which is open and not closed, and open sets which contain $U$. Then the intersection is $U$, which is open and not closed. For instance the sets $\{(0,n)\}_{n \geq 1}$.
3. If the sets are pairwise disjoint, then they have empty intersection.