# Extending vector bundle morphism. Do I need compactness?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles

The following corresponds to exercise 1 in Sec 1, Chp. 4 of Hirsch's book *Differential Topology*.

> Let $\xi,\eta$ be two vector bundles over the same base $B$. Assume that $B$ us paracompact and $A\subset B$ is closed. Then, every bundle map $f:\xi|_A \rightarrow \eta|_A$ covering $id_A$ extends to a bundle morphism $f:\xi|_A \rightarrow \eta|_A$ covering $id_W$, for some neighbourhood $W$ of $A$.

My idea is to use the fact that the base is paracompact to apply Tietze extension theorem: *If $X$ is a normal topological space and $A\subset X$ is closed, then every continuous function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb R$ extends to a function $\tilde f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$*.

Let $\{(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ and $\{(V_\beta,\psi_\beta)\}_{\beta\in \Xi}$ be a family of vector bundle charts for $\xi$ and $\eta$ covering $A$. By taking the intersections if necessary and restricting the charts, we can assume that $\Lambda=\Xi$ and that $U_\alpha=V_\alpha$.

Let $F_{\alpha\beta}$ denote the induced map by $\varphi_\alpha|^{-1}_{E|_{A\cap U_\alpha}}f \psi_\beta|^{-1}_{F|_{A\cap U_\beta}} : U_\alpha\cap U_\beta \times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow U_\alpha\cap U_\beta \times \mathbb R^m$ given by

$$
(x,\vec v) \longmapsto (x,F_{\alpha\beta}(\vec v)) .
$$

Fix $\vec v\in\mathbb R^n$ and define $m$ maps

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_{\vec v}^j :A & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\
 x & \longmapsto & \bigg (F_{\alpha\beta}(\vec v)\bigg)^j,
\end{array}
$$

where $x$ belongs to $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ (here $\alpha$ can be equal to $\beta$). We can use a partition of unity to fix the definitions on the overlaps $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\cap U_{\alpha'}\cap U_{\beta'}$ and get well-defined functions on $A$.

Using Tietze Extension Theorem, each $F_{\vec v}^j$ extends to a neighbourhood $W_{\vec v}^j$ of $A$ (let me use the same symbols to denote the extension). Let $W_{\vec v}$ be their intersection and set

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_{\vec v} :W_{\vec v} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R^m, \\
 x & \longmapsto & \bigg (F_{\alpha\beta}(\vec v)^1,\dots,F_{\alpha\beta}(\vec v)^m\bigg).
\end{array}
$$

**Now, if $A$ is compact**, the cover $\{W_{\vec v}\}_{\vec v\in\mathbb R^n}$ admits a finite subcover. Define $W$ as its intersection and put

$$
V = W \cap \left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} U_\alpha \right).
$$

Finally, I define $\tilde f: \xi|_V \rightarrow \eta|_V$ as the bundle morphism whose local representations are

$$
(x,\vec v) \longmapsto (x,F_{\vec v}|_{U_\alpha\cap U_\beta}(x)) .
$$

I am not sure if my proof is correct, even assuming compactness. And even if it is, I find it rather complicated. The exercise in the book does not present an asterisk, which means that the exercise should not be really demanding.

Hence, is my proof correct (assuming compactness)? Is there a simpler proof (for the compact case)? And how can I prove the result when $A$ is not assumed to be compact?

Comment: I am not fully following the intricacies of your proof here, but, if your concern is about being well-defined on intersections, then this can be alleviated by taking "locally finite" covers, that is, every point has a neighborhood that intersects only finitely many of the chart domains. So, no issue here. And a for the extension to the possibly infinite union, we need not worry as the partition of unity is precisely the tool to take care of such constructions!

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli: First, let me aplogise for the delaying answering your comment. I have fixed some typos my question had. Unfortunately, I cannot understand how a locally finite covering can help me here. Could you please develop a little bit more your comment? Thank you.

Comment: For instance to show why your maps are smooth, using the finite cover fact for any point there exists a ball around that point which lies in all of the coverings. And by construction all the maps from different covers agree on this ball. So, the map restricted to this ball is as smooth as the individual ones on local patches. Since, regularity is a local property, this proves smoothness. This is how (local) finiteness helps.

Comment: "There exists a ball around that point which lies in all of the coverings". Do you mean in all of the elements of the open covering? Or are you considering different open coverings?

Comment: No, in each of the elements of the original covering.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not true. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287245/the-intersection-of-a-locally-finite-family-of-open-sets-is-a-closed-set) question, the intersection of an infinite locally finite open covering is empty, so there cannot exist a ball contained in all the elements of the open covering in general.

Comment: What is the definition of locally finite you are using?

Comment: I say that $\{A_i \}$ is a locally finite family of sets if for each point $x$ in the space there exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ that meets only fonitely many elements $A_i$. I think is the usual one.

Comment: So, pick a ball completely contained in $V$. Doesn't this verify my assertion?

Comment: But $V$ is constructed after assuming compactness. If you don't assume compactness but only that $\{W_{\vec v}\}_{\vec v\in\mathbb R^n}$ is locally finite, then $V=\emptyset$.